# What framework is used to enable cross-language communication in mozilla platform?

Tags: javascript, python, c++, thunderbird

How do cross platform files communicate between each other? I got a chance to go through thunderbird code and I found whole framework comprised of javascript, python, xul and c++ files.

I am surprised to see whole framework.   Can anyone guide me about how they communicate with each other?

What is happening when we execute "make" commands?

Comment: I like this question as it's a question that i often asked myself not too long time ago. But, i feel this question is a bit broad. They can basically just communicate with a file, a connection or anything.

Comment: Read about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface

Comment: Almost certainly though C++ API(s). See (for example) [Simplified Wrapper and Interface Generator](http://www.swig.org/).

Answer (score 4):

Mozilla uses [XPCOM technology](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/XPCOM) to integrate components written in different languages.

> XPCOM is a cross platform component object model, similar to
>   Microsoft COM. It has multiple language bindings, allowing XPCOM
>   components to be used and implemented in JavaScript, Java, and Python
>   in addition to C++. Interfaces in XPCOM are defined in a dialect of
>   IDL called XPIDL.
>
> XPCOM itself provides a set of core components and classes, e.g. file
>   and memory management, threads, basic data structures (strings,
>   arrays, variants), etc. The majority of XPCOM components are not part
>   of this core set and are provided by other parts of the platform (e.g.
>   Gecko or Necko) or by an application or even by an extension.